# Should I set the time in a container?

Tags: systemd, ntp, clock, container

I have a few containers (`systemd-nspawn` based) and I am wondering whether I should set up the time (via `systemd-timesyncd`) or is it maintained by the host?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently **(*)**, there is no virtualisation of the time ressource in a container, *ie* there is no "time namespace". That means that should you succeed in changing the time in a container (by overriding some sane default limits existing in every containerization application), you would change the host's time. So the answer is not only you shouldn't, but also you should not be allowed to.

**(*)** this might change someday: [Time namespaces](https://lwn.net/Articles/766089/)